# rename a file in windows but save the previous name

Tags: windows, rename

I have a file with 1000 wav items and I want to change their name but somehow save their previous name within file details. (I mean rename the file, then by right clicking on file and /properties/details see the previous name saved somewhere there!)
Is it possible?
or do I have to use another trick?

Example: my wav file name is MK100.wav and I change its name to 1.wav but when I see the file's details the MK100.wav is saved, so I know that 1 is MK100!

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You could simply not rename the file in the first place. This feels like an XY question. Why did you ask this question?

Comment: This is a programming question, right? What language are you coding in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can. you need to add the info to the metadata.

http://blogs.loc.gov/digitalpreservation/2013/01/name-that-tune-adding-labels-and-descriptions-into-your-audio-files/

Comment: How would this be implemented programmatically?